# Sharing software updates between macs without OS X Server

Tags: macos, mac

Is there any way to (manually or automatically) share downloaded software updates between macs?

**Edit:** The thinking is that I have one mac update itself using Software Update, and then somehow share the downloaded updates with other macs.

For example, I have a mac pro and a mac mini on my local network. I'd like to download the Mac OS X 10.6.5 update only once, instead of having to download it separately for each mac.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you download the sofware update manually not using Software update from Apple e.g. [list of support downloads](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macosx106) As [Apple says](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4150)

> You can manually download the update
>   installer. This is a useful option
>   when you need to [update](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macosx106) multiple
>   computers but only want to download
>   the update once. These versions of the
>   standalone installers are available
>   from Apple Support Downloads.

Answer (score -1):

Manually? Just [download it once](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1325).

Automatically? You run Mac, not Windows. It doesn't have features like [WSUS](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wsus).

Comment: Actually, OS X has a feature a lot like WSUS -- It's called the Software Update service, and (like WSUS) requires a server to download updates and provide them locally to clients (and/or other servers).

Comment: Not all Macs use the same Delta updaters, you'll have to manually donwload the Combo updates and then share those with the rest of your Macs.